# How to alert the chosen option from HTML option select using javascript function?

Tags: html, function, html-select

```js
function myFunction() {
  var chosen = document.getElementById("input").value;
  alert(chosen);
}
```

```html
<select id="input" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option selected>Choose...</option>
      <option>ONE</option>
      <option>TWO</option>
      <option>THREE</option>
      <option>FOUR</option>
    </select>
```

So what I am trying to achieve, is when the user selects from the list (ONE, TWO, THREE or FOUR), then it should alert their selection to the window.

However, this doesn't work for me.

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: make sure your scrip is loaded on the related page

Comment: The code works.  The issue is probably due to where you're placing the script.  Try placing it near the end of the `body` tag.  Unfortunately without information about how you're including the JS, it's hard to know for certain what the cause is.